# gdb dump memory with no end_addr

Tags: linux, gdb

I want to inspect an array of unknown size using gdb in a Linux environment by dumping the memory to a file. I don't care if some extra memory is dumped as well. So something like

```
dump binary memory x.bin start_addr end_addr
```

but without needing to know end_addr. Say by just dumping memory until an address is encountered that is not mapped. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

> Is this possible?

You should be able to get that by setting an upper limit on how much you want dumped. E.g. this will dump up to 16MiB:

```
dump binary memory x.bin start start+0x1000000
```